# (Ir)rationality of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am working on this proof and this is what I got so far, can someone help me verify if what I have done is right?

> For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x+y$ is rational and $x-y$ is irrational
>   then $x$ is irrational and $y$ is irrational.

Proving the contrapositive and since contrapositive is logically equivalent to the original statement, we can conclude the original statement.

Contrapositive: For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x$ is rational or $y$ is rational, then $x+y$ is irrational or $x-y$ is rational.

Proof: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $x$ is rational. Then let $y = x$. We want to prove that $x+y$ is irrational or $x-y$ is rational.
Since $x$ is rational, we know that $x = a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b \not= 0$.
and $y = -x$
then $x-y = x-x = 0$, since $0$ is integer, and it is rational, that implies that $x-y$ is rational. End of Proof.

Now, can someone help me prove the original statement? Without trying with contrapositive?

Comment: Your proof is technically incorrect because you say "suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers" which implies that $x$ and $y$ are both arbitrary, but then you say "let $y = -x$" which implies that $y$ is not arbitrary. You also then wrote that $x - y = x-x$ but this is wrong because $y = -x$ implies $x - y = x-(-x) = 2x$ which is only $0$ if $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo.

Answer (score 7):

You can proceed directly as follows: $2x = (x+y) + (x-y)$ which must be irrational as it is the sum of a rational and an irrational. So $x$ is irrational. Similarly $2y = (x+y) - (x-y)$ is irrational.

Comment: Thanks John, but I don't understand. Where is the 2x coming from?

Comment: The original statement is: For all real numbers x and y, if x+y is rational and x-y is irrational then x is irrational and y is irrational.

Comment: In my answer I'm showing that given the original statement, I can conclude that $2x$ must be irrational. And $2x$ is irrational if and only if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Based on the original statement, you only know that x and y are real numbers, such that x+y is rational and x-y is irrational. You do not know `2x=(x+y)+(x-y)` - am I missing anything?

Comment: @Samim: you are missing the fact that addition of real numbers is allowed and useful in this problem. Knowing that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers (no matter which ones) is enough to conclude that $2x = (x+y) + (x-y)$.

Comment: thanks, but I am only allowed to use the definition of rational numbers and irrational numbers and the fact that sqrt(2) is irrational.

Comment: @Samim: but you are clearly allowed to use addition/subtraction, otherwise you couldn't write expressions such as $x+y$ and $x-y$.

Comment: So, is this what you mean: Proof: Suppose x and y are real numbers such that x+y is rational and x-y is irrational. We want to prove x is irrational and y is irrational. We know that x+y is rational, that is x+y = a/b where a, b are integers, b != 0. Where would you go from here?

Comment: I cannot use the fact that addition of rational number and irrational number is irrational. I need to show that.

Comment: @Samim: then you should show it. It is important and can be deduced by looking at the formula for addition/subtraction of rational numbers. The underlying fact is that the rational numbers ($\mathbb{Q}$) are $\textit{closed under addition}$.

Comment: please see my answer, what do you think?

Comment: can you check answer below? @john